# Docker Jenkins Home (/var/jenkins_home) Folder Permissions Issues when running from Compose

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-plugins

I build a custom Jenkins master image from jenkins lts image. Nothing very fancy but just a few convenience changes made to enable ssh communication

```
USER root
RUN usermod -u 105 jenkins && usermod -g nogroup jenkins
RUN mkdir -p /var/cache/jenkins && chown -R jenkins:nogroup /var/cache/jenkins && mkdir -p /var/log/jenkins && chown -R jenkins:nogroup /var/log/jenkins
RUN mkdir -p /home/jenkins/.ssh/
COPY id_rsa* /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/
RUN chmod 600 /var/jenkins_home/.ssh/id_rsa*
RUN chown -R jenkins:nogroup /home/jenkins/.ssh && chown -R jenkins:nogroup /var/jenkins_home

USER jenkins
```

There are reasons with the build and test infrastructure that needed changing user id for jenkins user from 1000 (on the jenkins lts image) to 105.

There are two volumes jenkinsHome and jenkinsLog that are mounted to the Jenkins master at `/var/jenkins_home` and `/var/log/jenkins`, respectively.

When starting the Jenkins master based on a custom image (with above changes) using `docker run` command `/var/jenkins_home` folder has right permissions and volume gets mounted successfully.

```
jenkins@012696fe9af6:/$ ls -la /var/
total 56
..
..
drwxr-xr-x 31 jenkins jenkins 12288 Jan  3 18:42 jenkins_home
```

However, when I start from the jenkins master using docker-compose /var/jenkins_home has owner set to 1000. Since there is no user with id 1000 on the master image, jenkins fails to start since the permissions on the jenkins_home are

```
jenkins@012696fe9af6:/$ ls -la /var/
total 56
..
..
drwxr-xr-x 31 1000 jenkins 12288 Jan  3 18:42 jenkins_home
```

QUESTIONS:

- Can someone please help me figure out why or how the owner for the jenkins_home folder seems to be different when starting the service using docker run vs docker compose ?
- It is not clear whether some how the entrypoint command for the lts image is changing the permissions. I feel it is unlikely because I explicitly set permissions on that folder `/var/jenkins_home` in the custom image that I use for spinning up the Jenkins master ?

FWIW - I have tried running the docker run command with the `--user 105:nogroup` flag and docker-compose with `user: 105:nogroup` to enforce users that are starting the container(docker run) and/or service(docker-compose). Also, a user with id 105 does exist on the host VM.

DOCKER RUN COMMAND

```
docker run --user 105:65534 -dit --log-opt max-size=10m --log-opt max-file=3 --restart unless-stopped -p 12345:8080 -t --name=master  -p 50000:50000 --volumes-from=daas-jenkins-data -e JENKINS_OPTS="-Dhudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.trackCredentials=false --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --handlerCountMax=300" -e JAVA_OPTS="-Duser.timezone=America/New_York -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Xmx4096m" jenkins-custom-master
```

DOCKER COMPOSE FILE

```
version: '3.5'
services:

  jenkins:
    image: jenkins-custom-master
    container_name: jenkins-master-svc
    volumes:
      - type: volume
        source: jenkinsHome
        target: /var/jenkins_home
      - type: volume
        source: jenkinsLog
        target: /var/log/jenkins
    ports:
      - "12345:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    environment:
      - JENKINS_OPTS=-Dhudson.plugins.sshslaves.SSHLauncher.trackCredentials=false --logfile=/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log --webroot=/var/cache/jenkins/war --handlerCountMax=300
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=America/New_York -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2 -Xmx4096m
    user: 105:65534
    networks:
      - jenkins-network  

  nginx:
    image: nginx-custom
    container_name: jenkins-nginx-svc
    ports:
      - "443:443"
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - jenkins-network  

networks:
  jenkins-network:
    name: jenkins-network

volumes:
  jenkinsHome:
    external: true
  jenkinsLog:
    external: true
```

Comment: Can you show your `docker-compose.yml` file for launching jenkins ? The exact `docker run ...` command you used to launch it manually would also be valuable (to have a point of comparison).

Comment: I sure can. Updated both above.